# Replacing Lambda expression - Lambda expression -> should be replaced as my Java does not support

Tags: java

```
for(String s : file1List){                               
System.out.println("*****************************");    
System.out.println("Checking for: "+s);                 
System.out.println("*****************************");      
file2List.removeIf(s1->s1.contains(s));                 
System.out.println("*************END****************");
```

I want to replace the lambda expression (`s1->s1.contains(s)`).

Comment: You want to replace it with Java 7?

Comment: so replace it? or better yet, update your Java to a version that does support lambda

Comment: If you use a Java version < 8, you don't have the `removeIf` method either.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade to Java 8. I am non JAVA professional. I have JAVA 7 installed.

Comment: Could you please someone help me replacing the code compatible with  JAVA 7 or substituting removeIf method.

Comment: @Shankar then don't write/copy Java 8 code. start with learning basic java, instead of copying code you found somewhere and ask others to "fix" what doesn't have to be fixed. You don't have to be a professional developer to have Java 8 on your system

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade Javato >= 8**

I would suggest upgrading to java-8 so you can use lambda's and removeIf but there is possibly a reason you cannot. In that case see next part

**Solving in Java <8**

Removing elements from a list while iterating over the list had some difficulties pre java-8. see [removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/removing-elements-on-a-list-while-iterating-through-it)

You would also need to replace the removeIf statement so you would replace

```
file2List.removeIf(s1->s1.contains(s));
```

with something like:

```
for(String s1 : new new ArrayList<>(file2List)) {
    if (s1.contains(s)) {
        file2List.remove(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try the above and share the outcome.

Comment: @Shankar btw the upgrade part of the answer was mostly for general consumption of this Q&A I already assumed upgrading in your case was not an option